# jQuery Ajax call script on success

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

This has been driving me nuts for a few days. I am desperate for help.

I have 2 files, index.php and test.php, simplied version to follow.

index.php

```
<div id="div-hi"></div>
<div id="div-bye"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ setInterval(function(){
$( function() 
{
$.ajax( 
{
url : 'test.php',
type : 'post',
success : function( resp ) 
    {
    $('#div-hi').html(resp);
    $('#div-bye').html(resp);
    }
});return false;}
);}, 1000);});  
</script>
```

test.php

```
<div id="hi">
<script type="text/javascript">
---
</script>
</div>

<div id="bye">
<script type="text/javascript">
----
</script>
</div>
```

I want #div-hi in index.php to contain the result of my javascript from #hi from test.php and #div-bye from index.php to contain the result from #bye from test.php.

I have ran out of ideas. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Javascript:**

You've got a few extra brackets and parens, and I don't know what the `return false` is doing in this case...

The format for **[setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)** is

```
setInterval( CODE, DELAY);
```

using an anonymous function with **[`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)** that's:

```
setInterval( function() { $.ajax( ... ) }, 1000);
```

Also, `return false` is usually used to cancel defualt behavior in jQuery.... it doesn't apply here.

If your response is HTML, you can extract a div from it with **[`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** or a **[context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)**.

Try something like this:

```
<div id="div-hi"></div>
<div id="div-bye"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax( 
        {
            url : 'test.php',
            type : 'post',
            success : function( resp ) 
            {
                  // Find the #hi and #bye divs in resp
                  //   and display them in #div-hi and #div-bye
                $('#div-hi').html($("#hi", resp).html());
                $('#div-bye').html($("#bye", resp).html());
            }
        });       
    } , 1000);
});  
</script>
```

### **[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cK3gW/)**

( note how the `{}`s appear after a few secs )

---

**Extracting DIVs from a page:**

Use the [**`.load()`**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function if you simply want to load pieces of another page onto the current page.

For example if you're on `index.php` and you want to grab the contents of `#hi` and `#bye` from `test.php` and display them in `#div-hi` and `#div-bye`

```
$('#div-hi').load('test.php #hi');
$('#div-bye').load('test.php #bye');
```

The above is two calls though, but I just wanted to illustrate the use of `.load()`.